# Area of a circle Using points from a cartesian plane

Tags: c++, c, struct

I have the following code which says that 'distance' is used uninitialized in this function.

This is a code that accepts two coordinates from a cartesian plane and uses the distance between them as radius to find the area of a circle. This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Point {
    int x, y;
};


double getDistance(struct Point a, struct Point b)
{
    double distance;
    distance = sqrt((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y-b.y) *(a.y-b.y));
    return distance;
}



int main()
{
    float Area;
    double distance;
    struct Point a, b;
    printf("Enter coordinate of point a: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a.x, &a.y);
    printf("Enter coordinate of point b: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &b.x, &b.y);
    printf("Distance between a and b: %lf\n", getDistance(a, b));

    Area= 3.14 * distance * distance;
    printf("\nArea of Circle : %f", Area);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be C or C++? And what's the actual error message, including filename and line number?

Comment: The variable `distance` in `getDistance()` is in a different scope, so is completely unrelated to the variable `distance` in `main()`.

Comment: Of course it does. Look at the `main` function. You declare a variable called `distance`, but never initialize it. Then, you do `Area= 3.14 * distance * distance;` Oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to assign `distance` variable, try something like:

```
int main()
{
  float Area;
  double distance;
  struct Point a, b;
  printf("Enter coordinate of point a: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &a.x, &a.y);
  printf("Enter coordinate of point b: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &b.x, &b.y);
  distance = getDistance(a, b);
  printf("Distance between a and b: %lf\n", distance);

  Area= 3.14 * distance * distance;
  printf("\nArea of Circle : %f", Area);


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is correct: variable `distance` inside `getDistance` and variable `distance` inside `main` are two different variables.

When you write this

```
printf("Distance between a and b: %lf\n", getDistance(a, b));
```

`distance` inside `main` does not get set.

You can fix it by adding an assignment

```
distance = getDistance(a, b);
printf("Distance between a and b: %lf\n", distance);
```

**Implementation note:** Since you need distance squared, you can avoid taking square root by defining a function `getDistanceSquared`, and using it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should read more carefully the compiler warning, because it is refering to the variable `distance` in your `main` function not the one in `getDistance`.

I think, what you actually wanted to do was this:

```
distance = getDistance(a, b);
printf("Distance between a and b: %lf\n", distance);
```

Then, you can use the result of `getDistance` anywhere in your `main` function. ;)